# Why dotnet core applications require base os image in docker?

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

Images like `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0` has base os image. Dotnet runtime provides all libraries required by dotnet application, in that case why dotnet application need base os image? I understand that base os image uses the same kernel as host, and base os only provides libraries for the application, but as I mentioned earlier dotnet runtime binary provides all the libraries required for dotnet application, then why do we need base os image? Does dotnet runtime depends on any os libarary, if so how do we know what libraries it depends on?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasons why .NET applications running in Docker still need a base OS image, even though the .NET runtime provides many libraries:

1. The .NET runtime itself depends on some basic OS functionality like
   filesystem access, networking, process management, etc. The base OS
   provides these low-level capabilities that the runtime builds on top
   of.
2. The base OS provides fundamental tools like a shell, basic utilities, package managers, etc. These are useful for running commands/scripts during Docker build, debugging issues, installing additional packages if needed, etc.
3. The base OS establishes the Linux distro and versions of libraries the container will use. The runtime guarantees ABI compatibility across distros, but having an explicit base pins down the OS libs and behavior.
4. Having a base OS image provides consistency with how other applications are containerized. All containers are built on a base OS, so it's a standard pattern.
5. The base OS provides the main init system and process supervisor for the container. The runtime doesn't include init systems like systemd, so the base OS provides process management.

What I would do is to create a minimal container with just the runtime and analyze it to see what OS packages are still needed.

*For example, Alpine is a minimal Linux distro, so Alpine-based .NET images will include fewer extra libs vs. Debian-based ones. But in general, Microsoft tries to optimize the .NET Docker images to only include essential OS packages on top of the runtime.*

Comment: @itsmedanncy, If we make a call like File.Open, c# will make system call, this will be handled by host kernel right? Am I wrong?

Comment: @Mohanraja You're correct that things like File.Open() ultimately make native system calls that are handled by the host kernel. The .NET runtime can't operate in isolation, it expects an OS below it to provide core services. The base image provides this layer.

.NET relies on OS libraries like libc, basic shell commands, filesystem access, user management, networking, process management and other fundamental OS capabilities. The specific libraries depend on the target Linux distribution.

Comment: @Mohanraja if this answer helped you please mark it as complete :)